# nub not compiling when checking a list for duplicates

Tags: list, haskell, typeclass, sudoku

Working on a sudoku inspired assignment and I need to implement a function that checks if a `Block Cell` has no repeated elements in it (to check if its a valid solution to the puzzle).

```
okBlock :: Block Cell -> Bool
okBlock b = okList $ filter (/= Nothing) b
 where
  okList :: [a]-> Bool
  okList list
   | (length list) == (length (nub list)) = True
   | otherwise                            = False
```

- `Block a = [a]`
- `Cell = [Maybe Int]`

Haskell complains saying `No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of "==" Possible fix: add (Eq a) to the context of the type signature for okList...`

Adding `Eq a` to the type signature does not help. I have tried the function in the terminal and it works fine for for lists, and for lists of lists (i.e the type I am feeding it in the function).

What am I missing here?

Comment: `okList :: Eq a =>  [a]-> Bool` should do

Comment: @DanielSanchez I knew it had to be simple, was adding it to the type signature for okBlock. For future reference is the type signature in the where clause actually necessary? would I avoid this problem if I didn't define it?

Comment: Local type signatures are indeed usually not necessary, but they can definitely make some sense in big functions where it's hard to see what the local functions are supposed to do. In this case, I'd leave the local signature, but specialise it to the type instantiation that's actually used: `okList :: [Cell] -> Bool`. Or else make it a _global_ definition with the general type `Eq a => [a] -> Bool`, and a more descriptive name like `hasNoDuplicates`.

Comment: some notes unrelated to your question: you might find `catMaybes` useful, be aware of the time complexity of `nub` and `length`, useless use of guard where right-hand side is a `Bool`; instead: `okList list = length list == length (nub list)`

Comment: @jberryman i actually define my own catMaybe as the assignment calls for `Nothing` s to be returned as '.' s, but I confess I did not know of it before and i will definitely use it later :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can only filter out duplicates, if there is a **way to check whether two values are duplicates**. If we look at the type signature for `nub`, we see:

```
nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

So that means that in order to filter out duplicates in a list of `a`s, we need `a` to be an instance of the `Eq` class. We can thus simply forward the type constraint further in the signatures of the functions:

```
okBlock :: Block Cell -> Bool
okBlock b = okList $ filter (/= Nothing) b
 where
  okList :: Eq => [a] -> Bool
  okList list
   | (length list) == (length (nub list)) = True
   | otherwise                            = False
```

We do **not** need to specify that `Cell` is an instance of `Eq` because:

- `Int` is an instance of `Eq`;
- if `a` is an instance of `Eq`, so is `Maybe a`, so `Maybe Int` is an instance of `Eq`; and
- if `a` is an instance of `Eq`, so is `[a]`, so `[Maybe Int]` is an instance of `Eq`.

That being said we can do some syntactical improvements of the code:

- there is no need to work with guards if you simply return the result of the guard `True` and `False`, and
- you can use an *eta reduction* and omit the `b` in `okBlock`.
- you don't need parentheses around function application (unless to feed to result straight to another, non-infix function).

This gives us:

```
okBlock :: Block Cell -> Bool
okBlock = okList . filter (/= Nothing)
  where
    okList :: Eq => [a] -> Bool
    okList list = length list == length (nub list)
```

A final note is that usually you do **not have to specify a type signature**. In that case Haskell will aim to dervice the most generic type signature. So you can write:

```
okBlock = okList . filter (/= Nothing)
  where
    okList list = length list == length (nub list)
```

Now `okBlock` will have type:

```
Prelude Data.List> :t okBlock
okBlock :: Eq a => [Maybe a] -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Three points that are too big to make in a comment.

#### `nub` is horribly slow

`nub` takes `O(n^2)` time to process a list of length `n`. Unless you know the list is very short, this is the *wrong function* to use to remove duplicates from a list. Adding a bit more information about what sort of thing you're working with allows more efficient nubbing. The simplest, and probably most general, approach that isn't absolutely wretched is to use an `Ord` constraint:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

nubOrd :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nubOrd = go S.empty where
  go _seen [] = []
  go seen (a : as)
    | a `S.member` seen = go seen as
    | otherwise = go (S.insert a seen) as
```

#### `length` is wasteful

Suppose I write

```
sameLength :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
sameLength xs ys = length xs == length ys
```

(which uses the approach you did). Now imagine I calculate

```
sameLength [1..16] [1..2^100]
```

How long will that take? Calculating `length [1..16]` will take nanoseconds. Calculating `length [1..2^100]` will probably take billions of years using current hardware. Whoops. What's the right way? Pattern match!

```
sameLength [] [] = True
sameLength (_ : xs) (_ : ys) = sameLength xs ys
sameLength _ _ = False
```

#### Nubbing isn't the right solution to this problem

Suppose I ask `noDuplicates (1 : [1,2..])`. Obviously, there's a duplicate, right at the beginning. But if I use `sameLength` and `nub` to check, I will *never get an answer*. It will keep building the nubbed list and comparing it to the original list until the `seen` becomes so large it exhausts your computer's memory. How can you fix that? By directly calculating what you need:

```
noDuplicates = go S.empty where
  go _seen [] = True
  go seen (x : xs)
    | x `S.member` seen = False
    | otherwise = go (S.insert x seen) xs
```

Now the program will conclude that there's a duplicate the moment it sees the second `1`.

Comment: this is very good information (and warning) for the future, however I don't believe it will be a problem here as this function will only encounter lists of length 9 (a single row, column, or square of a sudoku), and I only work with 81 total elements